# how to disable fab hide animation for material design 3 on android

Tags: android, floating-action-button, material-components-android

i have converted my current android project to use material 3 design as follows

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimations</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryVariantColor</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/secondaryVariantColor</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">@style/TextAppearance.Literal</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nexus_sans_offcpro</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/nexus_sans_offcpro</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

and followed the migration steps outlined on the material3 web pages.

one of my activities has two fabs as follows that i `show()` and `hide()`

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_prev"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin3"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/dark_grey"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:hideMotionSpec="@null"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_navigate_before_24"
    app:tint="@color/accessible_orange"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin3"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:hideMotionSpec="@null"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/dark_grey"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_navigate_next_24"
    app:tint="@color/accessible_orange"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RelativeOverlap" />
```

when i hide() each fab an "odd" animation occurs, first the fab shrinks and completly disappears which i am happy with, then it momentarily reappears as a smaller version and finally this small version disappears.

is there any way i can disable this behaviour?

i tried setting the hideMotionSpec to @null however this had no effect.

do i need to set my own hide animation to achieve an improved UX?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar "problem" and I found a solution. In my case, it was in removing the `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` flag from the root of the layout where the fab is located.

It seems that this "odd" animation of showing/hiding a fab is its default animation.

`android:animateLayoutChanges` description:

> Defines whether changes in layout (caused by adding and removing
> items) should cause a LayoutTransition to run. When this flag is set
> to true, a default LayoutTransition object will be set on the
> ViewGroup container and default animations will run when these layout
> changes occur.

Try to look at your layout, maybe this flag is set in it. Or maybe you have a layout style that also has this flag set.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer as a 1 reputation user. Best of Luck...

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

**SHOW**

`myFab.visibility = View.VISIBLE` instead of use `myFab.show()`

```
myFab.startAnimation(myOwnShowAnim)
```

**HIDE**

`myFab.visibility = View.GONE` instead of use `myFab.hide()`

```
myFab.startAnimation(myOwnHideAnim)
```